Constant problem with integrating a differential equations .
This is a alevel maths question 

this is where i got up to before i was told i did it wrong ,apparently the right hand side should be 1/k * ln|n|. Both 1/k * ln|n| and the one in my picture will differentiate to 1/kn .
However with my answer apparently i have limited the values of the constant by making a relationship that doesnt exist by having (1/k *lnk )+c as my constant ?Im not sure what they mean by this .Can someone confirm why my integral on the right is wrong ?
PS i dont have degree level maths jargon .

Your integration is wrong. Pull out the constant from the integral sign and just integrate $\frac{1}{n}$
You'll get the desired answer.

Both of those expressions on differentiation give another expression (which is same for both) as they only differ by a constant. Expand $\ln|kn|$ and you'll see yourself.

yeah when i integrate my expression vs the correct one i still get 1/kn for both cases?

@jjose cuz they only differ by a constant... expand $\ln|kn|$ using laws of logarithms

i would get ln|k| +ln|n| but i dont see how this means the answer in the picture was wrong , if i further evaluted my answer i would get 1/k * ln|n| +((1/k * ln|k|)+c) =1/k * ln|n|+A which differentiates to 1/kn still .............?
